# Error occurred in deployment step 'Add Solution': Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1070

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, solution-deployment

i'm trying to develop App using visual studio on but when i try to deploy the app this error pop out in visual studio error. i was reading for the last few hours trying to find a solution but no joy following several forums and guidance.
first of all does this error is generic ?
or something that i need to to setup in my Sharepoint server.
P.s note that i'm the sole user of the server as it is installed in dev machine at home running Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a syntax error in some XML file. I'm afraid you have to check every one of them.

I would remove everything from the solution and start adding artifacts one by one and each time try to deploy.